# Extract data from NETCDF (.NC file) based on time

Tags: python, variables, extract, netcdf

I am currently working on extracting data from a `.NC` file to create a `.cur` file for usage in GNOME. I am doing this in python

I extracted the following variables.

```
water_u(time, y, x)
water_v(time, y, x)
x(x): 
y(y): 
time(time): time
SEP(time, y, x)
```

The cur file should contain the following:

```
[x][y][velocity x][velocity y]
```

this should happen for each  time variable present. In this case I have 10 time data extracted, but I have thousands and thousand of `[x][y]` and velocity.

My question is how to I extract the velocities based on the time variable?

```
import numpy as np 
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
volcgrp = Dataset('file_1.nc', 'r') 
var = volcgrp.variables['water_v'][:] 
print(var) 
newList = var.tolist() 
file = open('text.txt', 'w') 
file.write('%s\n' % newList) 
print("Done") 
volcgrp.close()
```

Comment: You're really going to need to give more details to have any chance of getting an answer to your question. Please show the code you've tried so far and describe what happens with it (does it raise an exception? If so, give the traceback). You might also need to provide an example of the data, though if you're not able to parse the file yet (and can't share it publicly), that might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Blckknght 
This is the code I tried so far
`code`
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
 
volcgrp = Dataset('file_1.nc', 'r')
var = volcgrp.variables['water_v'][:]
print(var)
newList = var.tolist()
file = open('text.txt', 'w')
file.write('%s\n' % newList)
print("Done")
volcgrp.close()
`code`
In this case I am trying to extract water_v and place it in a text file. My assignment is to make a file containing rows where on row1 and rows to comes water_v and water_u, respectively. This needs to happen for each time factor in the .NC file. 

Does this clarify it a bit?

Comment: Please put the code in the question, where you can format it properly (indentation matters in Python, so it's even more important than usual to have decent formatting).

Comment: @Blckknght just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to read in the `water_u` and `water_v` for each of its three dimensions and then you can access those variables along its time dimension.

```
import netCDF4

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('file_1.nc', 'r') 
time = ncfile.variables['time'][:]  #1D
water_u = ncfile.variables['water_u'][:,:,:] #3D (time x lat x lon)
water_v = ncfile.variables['water_v'][:,:,:]
```

To access data at each grid point for the first time in this file:

```
water_u_first = water_u[0,:,:]
```

To store this 3D data into a text file as you describe in the comments, you'll need to (1) loop over `time`, (2) access `water_u` and `water_v` at that time, (3) flatten those 2D arrays to 1D, (4) convert to strings if using the standard file.write technique (can be avoided using Pandas `to_csv` for example), and (5) write-out the 1D arrays as rows in the text file.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I will try it and inform you about my results! Again thank you